# Reputation leagues - displaying profile picture for the non-entry exist periods

Tags: support, profile-picture, reputation-leagues

In the [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/) page, if there is no entry for the period of month, quarter and year, some user's profile picture is displayed in the leagues page.

For an example in the *Stellar* and *Constructed Languages* sites Adam Lear's profile picture is displayed.   For *Augur*, [David Cosier](https://augur.stackexchange.com/users/1614/) profile picture is displayed, there he has only one reputation.

So basis on what scenario, their profile picture is displaying in the leagues page?

> [image: GIF]

Comment: Adam is User #1, which is likely *why* he's listed there. Whether that's good behavior or not...

Comment: @Catija Where as in Augur [David Cosier](https://augur.stackexchange.com/users/1614/david-cosier) is not the User #1, he has only 1 reputation there.

Comment: ... that looks like a spam account. :(